# Implemented a progress calculator for an upload task but it does not add the url of the item properly through this method

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, material-ui, firebase-storage

I want to add a progress calculator for this task in order to display a progress feedback to user.

I've tried this but it doesn't add the url to my `setUrl(url)` hook which causes a problem.

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(eventImage) {

        const uploadImage = storage.ref(`EventImages/${values.eventName}`).put(eventImage);
        uploadImage.on('state_changed',
            (snapshot) => {
                    // progrss function ....
                    const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
                    this.setState({progress});
                  }
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            },
            () => {
                storage.ref('EventImages').child(values.eventName).getDownloadURL().then((url) =>{
                    console.log(url);
                    setUrl(url);
                })

            }
        );
        }

        dbref.add({
            eventName: values.eventName,
            eventVenue: values.eventVenue,
            eventAddress: values.eventAddress,
            eventCategory: values.eventCategory,
            eventOrganizer: values.eventOrganizer,
            eventPhone: values.eventPhone,
            eventEmail: values.eventEmail,
            eventDetails: values.eventDetails,
            eventDate: selectedDate.toDateString(),
            eventTime: selectedDate.toLocaleTimeString(),
            eventImgUrl: eventImageUrl
        }).then((docRef) => {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
            setValues('');
            setImg('');
            setUrl('');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });

    }
```

I've tried this but it doesn't add the url to my `setUrl(url)` hook which causes a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly. But if you're trying to store the download URL of the image in the database, then you must do so in the callback that runs when the download URL is determined. That is the only place/moment that you're guaranteed to know the download URL.

So move the code that writes to the database into the `getDownloadURL().then()` callback:

```
const uploadImage = storage.ref(`EventImages/${values.eventName}`).put(eventImage);
uploadImage.on('state_changed',
    (snapshot) => {
            // progrss function ....
            const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
            this.setState({progress});
          }
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    },
    () => {
        storage.ref('EventImages').child(values.eventName).getDownloadURL().then((url) =>{
            dbref.add({
                eventName: values.eventName,
                eventVenue: values.eventVenue,
                eventAddress: values.eventAddress,
                eventCategory: values.eventCategory,
                eventOrganizer: values.eventOrganizer,
                eventPhone: values.eventPhone,
                eventEmail: values.eventEmail,
                eventDetails: values.eventDetails,
                eventDate: selectedDate.toDateString(),
                eventTime: selectedDate.toLocaleTimeString(),
                eventImgUrl: eventImageUrl
            }).then((docRef) => {
                console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
                setValues('');
                setImg('');
                setUrl('');
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
            });
        })

    }
);
```